# Send URL to sails lift command

Tags: node.js

I'm triying to send the URL to my datastore through sails lift, but i don't know how.

Could you please tell me some clue? (I'm using MySQL)

I triying something like:

sails lift --models.connection__url='mysql:\desarrollo:desarrollo@localhost:3306/pru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to pass it to `sails lift`, you can specify an [environment](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/configuration) and each environment can use different [datastores](https://sailsjs.com/config/datastores).